# Selenium driver.get() throws Exception

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

**When i'm running this code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Program Files 
(x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe')
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
```

It only opens my browser but not the URL that was passed as a parameter to `driver.get()`.

Given below is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\efiqq\OneDrive\Plocha\Python\Link.py", line 4, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe')
  File "C:\Users\efiqq\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 68, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\efiqq\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 98, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "C:\Users\efiqq\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 111, in assert_process_still_running
    % (self.path, return_code)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 0
```

Comment: I tried but it's still not working.

Comment: what happens if you remove the path, and use only `driver = webdriver.Chrome()`?

Comment: if you've added the chromedriver to your path, the path argument is optional: `driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.`, : ref: [ChromeDriver - WebDriver for Chrome](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/getting-started)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The path you have to pass is not to `chrome.exe`. You have to point to the `chromedriver.exe`;

You can get it here: http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads